# Add class only on first slide the first time the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have implemented a slideshow using Bootstrap Carousel. As you guys might now, this carousel is pretty basic so I wanted to add some eye candy to it.

Using the animate.css transitions, I wanted to only animate the first slide. I tried

```
$('.caption-wrapper').addClass('scrollpoint sp-effect3');

setTimeout(function () { 

$('.caption-wrapper').removeClass('scrollpoint sp-effect3 animated fadeInDown');

}, 2000);
```

and it works! However, as you can see, I am adding and removing a class using the setTimeout function (which is kind of weird).

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're doing. What sort of animation and when? Based on your 2 second timeout, I'd guess you'd want to use the events available instead. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events

Comment: Even though my question was not clear, you helped me open my eyes to the right answer, you rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, as mentioned by @isherwoord, I used Bootstrap carousel available events, in this case the "slide" event. Here's the answer:

```
$('#slideshow').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {

  $('.caption-wrapper').removeClass('scrollpoint sp-effect3 animated fadeInDown');

});
```

This a lot more elegant solution to what I originally had.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function slider(){
       $('.caption-wrapper').addClass('scrollpoint sp-effect3',function(){
       setTimeout(function () { 
           $('.caption-wrapper').removeClass('scrollpoint sp-effect3 animated fadeInDown');
           }, 2000);
       });
   }
  setInterval(slider,3000);
});
```